# Efficiency when deleting rows in two tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have table1(id_table1) and table2(id_table2, id_table1). I'd like to remove records in table2 (under a given condition) but then also remove items in table1 that have no more relationships to table2. What is the most efficient way to do that in SQL? I'm using mySql.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you use InnoDB, add a foreign key constraint with an `ON DELETE CASCADE`. This will automatically delete the rows if the relationship is no longer correct. That way, you don't have to query the database after deleting rows in table2 to check if the relation is still intact.

[Foreign key constraints](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html)

Comment: Ok thanks but I don't think this is what I want. I'd like to delete the parent if it has no child anymore. Not only delete the childs if the parent is deleted as you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to cularis's answer a less efficient option, if you're using MyISAM you don't have foreign key constraints.

Create a trigger:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER ad_table1_each AFTER DELETE ON table2 FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  DELETE FROM table1 WHERE table1.table2_id = OLD.id;
END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/triggers.html
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-trigger.html

Comment: He wants to delete from table2 , and after that, if none of the records in table2 points to a row in table1,it should be removed.

Comment: @KaKa, that's exactly what this trigger does, You do know hwo triggers work don't you?

Comment: :I know how triggers work and i am certain that you too know how they work.Please read the question and my comment carefully.
In Marc's question table1 had only one column whereas yours has 2, it can mean 2 things
1)You reversed the names .Yeah, i have no problem with that.But that solves an entirely different simple problem of deleting all rows from table1 (having 2 columns) when rows from table2 (having single column) are deleted.

Comment: 2)Assuming you did a typo in script but solved it using trigger ,take a case when there are 2 rows in table2(having 2 cols) with same id_table1 value, deleting one of them will delete the row in table1 which is wrong.A row in table1 should be deleted only when ALL the rows pointing to it are deleted.

Comment: That's true KaKa is right, this is not exactly what I meant. I have table1(id) and table2(id, table1_id) and want to delete all rows in table1 that have no children.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you did not set up any cascading deletes and since you asked how to do it in sql, i can see two options:

1)delete from table2 where (condition)

```
delete from table1 where id not in (select distinct id_table1 from table2)
```

2)delete from table1 where id in (select distinct id_table1 from table2 where (condition))

```
delete from table2 where id_table2 not in (select id from table1)
```

Assuming table2 size is much larger than table1, and the condition considerably shortens the size 
method 1 scans full table2 once,deletes many records,then scans once
method 2 scans full table2 twice

This makes me think method 1 is little bit more efficient if the sizes of tables are very very large.

Comment: this does not look very efficient.

Comment: please explain why, triggers would not work in such case, so executing  2 queries is the only way i can think of (apart from cascading deletes)

Comment: I see no reason why triggers would not work, and `not In (select ...)` will be very very slow on MySQL, because the inner select will do a full table scan and will match all rows from table 2 with all rows from table2 again.

Comment: I thought using the first option but indeed it is not efficient and especially because table1 can have a lot of rows. That's why I asked the question... :-)

Comment: Gave reason why triggers wont work. Agreed that its not very efficient.